# Is it possible to get browser cookie file locally within sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I am using Sagemaker AWS notebook and I am curious if it is possible to get browser cookies from within sagemaker or is there any other way to get cookies from Sagemaker.

Right now I have the below code but of course its giving me an error.

```
import browser_cookie3
chromecookies = os.path.join(os.path.expandvars("%localappdata%"),"Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Network\\Cookies")

cookiejar = browser_cookie3.chrome(cookie_file=chromecookies, domain_name="www.google.com")
print(cookiejar)
```

Has anyone been able to run a python script that allows you to get cookies from a browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a particular site, you can use something like -

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('http://google.com')
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
```

Since SageMaker notebook runs on a remote server, I don't think your localappdata will resolve to the right location.